# Javascript and its never ending mystery

Tags: javascript

Have been learning Javascript far past few months still here I end. :(

Got this below question in an interview:

```
var age = 10;
var obj = {
    age: 54,
    foo: () => {
      console.log(this.age);
    }
  }

const { foo } = obj;
foo();   //10
```

What changes would be required to make it print "54" instead of "10"?

Will appreciate a lot if someone can suggest me some source where I can study the in-depth of javascript and its engine in detail but in laymen terms.

Comment: `this` changes depending on how the method is called. In your example `this` is likely the global object, and `age` is a property on that object. So `this.age` is `10`

Comment: This only prints `10` when in a browser, not in e.g. a Node.js script, where there is no global `this`.

Comment: Which part are you allowed to change?

Comment: @AKX - There is, it's just normally code isn't using it. But try `node < script.js` and the code runs at global scope (and prints 10). :-)

Comment: simple: `var age = 10;
var obj = {
    age: 54,
    foo: () => {
      console.log(obj.age);
    }
  }

const { foo } = obj;
foo();`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what does the `<` signify here, and why does it run node with a global scope?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, yeah. Fixed to the more precise "Node.js script" :-)

Comment: @evolutionxbox - It's command line redirection of `stdin`. Node runs code from `stdin` at global scope. Otherwise, it defaults to running files as modules (of one kind or another).

Comment: @AKX - Even in them, there's a global this value, it's just not being used in that specific case. You access it via its other name, `globalThis`. (I'm not kidding you, that's in the standard now. :-D )